# call_user_func_array() error

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using wordpress 4.0, and I get the following php warnings in my log:

> PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'et_add_viewport_meta' not found or invalid function name in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/blog/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 505

I checked the plugin.php line 505, and found this line:

> call_user_func_array($the_['function'], array_slice($args, 0, (int) $the_['accepted_args']));

How can I fix this, what can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check your wordpress functions.php under **~/wp-content/themes/YOURTHEMENAME/** directory.

There should be this function defined:

```
function et_add_viewport_meta(){
     echo '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />';
}
```